# mysql query error 3 table JOIN

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello i am trying to join 3 tables and get all information from them table names : fav,images,posts

fav table stores: userid,postid (this table is for favorite ads)

images table stores: postid,path(1-5)

posts table stores all information about post : id,userid,title etc

so now i am doing sql query witch should select everything from fav and joing post and images where `$_session["userid"] = to userid`
this how its looks like :

```
<?php

                    $userid = $_SESSION["userid"];

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM fav f JOIN posts p ON f.postid = p.id JOIN images i ON p.id = i.postid WHERE userid='$userid' ";
                    $res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
                     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                         $postid = $row["postid"];
                         ?>
                        <div id="ads">
                            <div id="titlepic">
                            <a href="review.php?id=<?php echo $postid; ?>"><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a><br>
                            <a href="review.php?id=<?php echo $postid; ?>"><img src="<?php if(!empty($row["path1"])) { echo $row["path1"]; } else echo "image/noimage.png"; ?>" height="100px" width="150px"></a>
                            </div>

                            <div id="dates">
                                <b>Date Added:</b> <?php echo date('m/d/Y H:i', $row["dateadded"]); ?><br>
                                <b>Renew Date:</b> <?php if($row["renewdate"] > 0){ echo date('m/d/Y H:i', $row["renewdate"]); } ?><br>
                                <b>Location:</b> <?php echo $row["location"]; ?><br>
                                <b>Price:</b> <?php echo $row["price"]."&pound"; ?><br>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr width="100%">
                        <?php
                     }

                ?>
```

but i get error after i put `WHERE userid='$userid'` error sounds like this `"Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\project\fav.php on line 129"`

where is the problem i don't get it cause if i don't do WHERE part everything works without warnings and errors

Comment: your query failed then and you need to find out what that is. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change query to

```
 $sql = "SELECT f.*,p.*,i.* FROM fav f JOIN posts p ON f.postid = p.id JOIN images i ON p.id = i.postid WHERE f.userid='$userid' ";
```

I assume userid belongs to fav f change it to p.userid or i.userid if it belongs to these table.

Comment: okay so the problem solve with a sample of yours f.userid='$userid' don't use all of your query cuz still are not that advanced and yours looks ore difficult

Answer (score 1):

This error mean , you have problem in your query.so try to run your query in phpmyadmin to see where is error come from.

maybe your problem :

`userid` is ambiguous in your query

so select which table must in where clause f or p :)

Comment: yea same told phpmyadmin so i use Rishi sampe and do it f.userid